# Is there any way to get rid of MasterPage while working in design view in ASP.net / Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I have just begun using ASP.net heavily.
In Visual Studio when I open a web form with a master page in design view, it is not really very comfortable to work with.
Is there any way to hide master page so that I can concentrate on my form ?

If not, can I use a user control as a web form and embed it into the actual form as a work around ? (I know it does not exist for this purpose)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master"` from the page header. when your design is complete add it again.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this will help. I always need to edit the pages many times after I create them. And the markup is quite different, not only "MasterPageFile=..."